# VBA How to get the next cell address

Tags: vba, excel, loops, while-loop

I am writing a piece of code to go through a loop, what I want to do is store the cell address `J2` in a variable and then each time the code runs through the loop get it to go onto the next cell down, i.e. `J2` would go to `J3` then `J3` would go to `J4` and so on.

This is what I've got at the minute and have tried:

```
Index = 0
CurrentCell = Range("J2").Address

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

RowsCount = Application.CountA(Range("A3:A" & Rows.Count))

While Index < RowsCount

    CurrentCell = CurrentCell + 1
    Recipients = CurrentCell + ";"
    Index = Index + 1

Wend
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what currentcell is meant to be doing (so I have removed it) but the set rng line will be set to each row

Replace your loop with below

```
While Index < RowsCount

    set rng = range("J2").offset(0+Index,0)
    Recipients = Recipients & rng.value & ";"
    Index = Index + 1

Wend
```

Comment: that works but doesn't provide me with an array of recipients in the variable `Recipients`, it just replaces what's in there each time

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This line should assign the address of the next cell:

```
CurrentCell = Range(CurrentCell).Offset(1, 0).Address
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at what you're trying to achieve:

```
Dim lIndex                As Long
Dim lLastRow              As Long

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
' find the number of the last populated row in column A
lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For lIndex = 2 To lLastRow
    ' append the values of each cell in column J to a string, separated by semicolons
    Recipients = Recipients & ";" & Cells(lIndex, "J").Value
Next lIndex
' strip off the leading semicolon by taking everything after the first character
Recipients = Mid$(Recipients, 2)
```

Comment: thank you for your post, can you please explain to me what these lines are doing: `lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, `Recipients = Recipients & ";" & Cells(lIndex, "J").Value`, `Recipients = Mid$(Recipients, 2)`

Comment: @BenSmith I've added some comments to the code. Note: I have assumed Recipients is a string variable used to store the addresses of the intended recipients (not really a good variable name here)